# How to pass ngFor index in ngClass

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass the ngFor with index inside ngClass to activate the correct class. I have tried different ways, but I have not been successful.

Here's the code:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-1-active' : classFocus.col1 , 'col-tb-1' : !classFocus.col1}">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

In this case, where it has "1", I want to change the index. Would be something like:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-1-active' : classFocus.col1 , 'col-tb-1' : !classFocus.col1}">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

I tried it that way, but it did not work:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-' + i + '-active' : 'classFocus.col' + i , 'col-tb-' + i : !'classFocus.col'+ i}">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

Comment: I guess your code won't work since classFocus is a variable not a string. Convert the variable to an array, and access it something like classFocus[i].col. Rest is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can try it this way:**

> I have provided a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dynamic-class)** for your reference as well.
>
> **Avoid** having it as *`classFocus.col + i`*, as it would not treat it as a variable with data on it.
>
> **Enclose** them in a **bracket [ ]** if you want a dynamic className and its condition
>
> **Use** conditional ternary operator **(?)** when dealing with 2 conditions that could either result in true or false

```
 <td *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index"
     [ngClass]="[classFocus['col' + i] ? 
                'col-tb-' + i + '-active' : 'col-tb-' + i]">
   {{ item }}
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are after the following:

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [class]="'col-tb-' + i + (classFocus['col' + i] ? '-active' : '')">{{ cell.value }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<td *ngFor="let cell of row; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'col-tb-' +{{ i }}+ '-active' : 'classFocus.col' + {{i }}, 'col-tb-' +{{ i }}: !'classFocus.col'+{{ i}}}">{{ cell.value }}</td`

Answer (score -1):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
    <tr [class]="'col'+i">{{item}}</tr>
</ng-container>
```